# Merge a rigified object with new armature for proxy linking

Tags: rigging, linked-data

I used rigify to create a rig for my character. After that, I created a separate armatures with 4 bones and set them as shape keys for blinking and smiling for my character. This new armature I called facerig, while the rest of the body is called rig. Now, when i am trying to link it to a scene and make a proxy, I can select rig, but how do I join the facerig to that proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join the two armatures (select the rig, shift select the facerig, press Ctrl J) and then make the proxy in the new scene.

Comment: if I'm selecting main rig first and then facerig, on ctrl+j, the main mesh disappears. And when i select facerig first and then main rig, the facerig armature disappears?

Comment: Before joining the two rigs Apply (Ctrl A) Loc Rot and Scale of both rigs and the mesh. If it still doesn't work you could upload your file.